# How to use pipenv to install package from github

Tags: python, pipenv

Using pipenv to install the spaCy package from github with

```
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#egg=spacy
```

I run into two problems:

(1) Install fails, because the following packages need to be installed before: `cython, preshed, murmurhash, thinc`. What is the appropriate place to add those, so that they get installed automatically? I tried `setup_requires` in `setup.py` but that didn't work.

(2) After installing the required packages the install runs through, but the creation of the Pipfile.lock fails with:

```
Adding -e git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#egg=spacy to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
_dependencies(best_match):
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 275, in _iter_dependencies
    for dependency in self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq):
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 202, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 221, in get_legacy_dependencies
    dist = ireq.get_dist()
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/req/req_install.py", line 1069, in get_dist
    egg_info = self.egg_info_path('').rstrip('/')
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/req/req_install.py", line 515, in egg_info_path
    'No files/directories in %s (from %s)' % (base, filename)
pip9.exceptions.InstallationError: No files/directories in None (from )
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use pip: `pip install spacy`?

Comment: Because (1) I want to track spacy-development from git, and (2) pipenv is the officially recommended package management tool.

Comment: @spbks That "officially recommended" line has been removed by PyPA.

Comment: @spbks Try it without the -e option

`pipenv install git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#egg=spacy`
If you are using a pipenv file, under the packages section you could add something like this
`spacy = {editable = true, git = "git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy"}`

Answer (score 17):

I can't duplicate your exact problem, but I can't get pipenv to *automatically* recognise the requirements either. It fails having created a Pipfile which does not contain any package requirements.

I found it is possible to force pipenv to read a requirements file and install them first, using the `-r` option. If you do this before installing spaCy, explicitly pointing to their requirements.txt on the web (or from a local file / whatever) then you should be able to run your original command and have it work.

```
pipenv install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/explosion/spaCy/master/requirements.txt
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#egg=spacy
```

**Edit:** I reported this to [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3015) and [spaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2844). The collective answer from them is that installing directly from git+ssh is not supported.

Comment: what does r stand for in pipenv install -r? Couldn't find it in the docs

Comment: @Barnabe Import a requirements.txt file. Short for --requirements

Answer (score 5):

I did install the *setuptools* first and omitted the -e

```
pipenv install setuptools
pipenv install git+https://github.com/nympy/numpy#egg=numpy
```

Next I was able to [download model](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#download-models) using

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

And ran the example

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"This is a sentence.")
```

#### Longer answer

Using the **-e** after a long time the error below popped up.

> pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/q0/23jhzjyd4c778437xkp_k4pc0000gn/T/tmpky4kwd64source/spacy/

This means all dependencies are compiled except spaCy.

Then installing without **-e**

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#egg=spacy
```

> Installing git+https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#egg=spacy…
>   Warning: You installed a VCS dependency in non-editable mode. This will work fine, but sub-dependencies will not be resolved by $ pipenv lock.
>   To enable this sub-dependency functionality, specify that this dependency is editable.

So I guess the spaCy dependencies are still kept around. Sound bad to me.